# What is the modern day equivalent of Firesheep?

Tags: firefox, security, https

[Firesheep](http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/) came out on the scene in 2010 and rocked the world... and never made it to version 1.0. Mozilla has since released 15 major versions of Firefox and is incompatible with the extension. Is there a version that works with the latest Firefox or is one [the 1000 forks on GitHub](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/network) considered the successor to Firesheep?

Comment: What is Firesheep?

Comment: bear in mind a lot of the security holes firesheep exposed on popular sites have since been closed.

Comment: @oliver. Firesheep was a way to really easily (as in point and click) hijack other peoples website sessions on things like facebook because the websites only ssl encrypted the login phase. It made alot of noise in the news due to people using it on public wifi hotspots. Many sites have since either began using ssl for everything by default or by a user-set option.

Comment: @Sirex is correct.  And StackExchange, sadly, is not yet one of those sites that have switched to full SSL.

Comment: The modern equivalent is to use HTTPS in the first place. Other than that you'll not need Firesheep for using Firefox...

Answer (score 7):

Cookie Cadger, being developed by a colleague of mine.  Terrifying Java app that steals cookies from a large number of apps:

http://igniteshow.com/videos/cookie-monster-unnoticed-threat-open-wi-fi

Edit: Available now at https://www.cookiecadger.com/

Comment: I would guess that making this a Java app in the current context makes it even easier to steal information.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, all that Firesheep did was sniff out unsecured packets and pulled the information from there. Unfortunately there isn't a replacement extension (to my knowledge), but there are other options.

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) does exactly this. I'm not as well versed in it's proper usage as I'd like to be, but there are many [guides](http://lifehacker.com/5853483/a-guide-to-sniffing-out-passwords-and-cookies-and-how-to-protect-yourself-against-it) out there that can help you utilize it's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [DroidSheep](http://droidsheep.de/) for Android (requires root). The [source is also available](https://code.google.com/p/droidsheep/).

Comment: driodsheep is used to get the password of a wpa wpa2 wifi connection not to get passwords for website log-ins i'm sure some of the base code could be used to make an adaptation to firesheep if someone was feeling froggie though

Comment: @tinkeringgnome: What are you talking about? Neither Firesheep nor Droidsheep get WPA Wi-Fi passwords. They "just" intercept cookies from HTTP connections.